# default argument promotions and relevance of "%c" in printf

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

Here's what `libc` has to say about variadic functions:

> Since the prototype doesn’t specify types for optional arguments, in a call to a variadic function the default argument promotions are performed on the optional argument values. This means the objects of type char or short int (whether signed or not) are promoted to either int or unsigned int, as appropriate; and that objects of type float are promoted to type double. So, if the caller passes a char as an optional argument, it is promoted to an int

Then, why would anyone use `"%c"`, or `"%hd"` in printf ? they should just use `"%d"`.

I also see that there's no format specifier for `float`. `float` has to live with `%f` which is for `double` since due to promotions, it's not possible to receive a float as a variadic argument.

I know for `scanf`, the arguments are pointers and no promotion happens.

Is there any reason I am missing why and when `"%c"` must exist for `printf`s?

Comment: What is "libc" for you?

Comment: please edit your comment to remove the attribution. I was asking for reason, there are many implementations of the C library around. To which one are you referring? You should cite your sources properly.

Comment: `%hd` is for `short`, I think you mean `%hhd`.

Comment: @JensGustedt yes sure. I read you wrong

Answer (score 5):

> Then, why would anyone use "%c", or "%hd" in printf ? they should just use "%d".

One would use `%c` to interpret the integer as its character code (i.e. print `'A'` instead of 65). One would use `%hd` to instruct `printf` to drop the upper portion of the `short` that may have been added as part of sign-extending the short value passed in. Both formats offer an alternative interpretation of an `int`.

> I also see that there's no format specifier for `float`.

That's correct: since the value has been promoted to `double`, there is no need for a separate flag.